# I am NOT able to Get Current Location using Google Map API

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to get current location using Google API, but my Map does not move to the current location when I turn my location switch, it does not zoom to my location. Here is my Code

```
package com.example.mac.uberclone;

import android.Manifest;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mac.uberclone.Common.Common;
import com.example.mac.uberclone.Remote.IGoogleAPI;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.JointType;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.SquareCap;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
{

private GoogleMap mMap;

//Play Service
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7000;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST = 7001;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;

private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

DatabaseReference drivers;
GeoFire geoFire;

Marker mCurrent = null;


MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

//Car Animation
private List<LatLng> polyLineList;
private Marker carMarker;
private float v;
private double lat,lng;
private Handler handler;
private LatLng startPosition,endPosition,currentPosition;
private int index,next;
//private Button btnGo;
private PlaceAutocompleteFragment places;
private String destination;
private PolylineOptions polylineOptions,blackPolylineOptions;
private Polyline blackPolyline,greyPolyline;

private IGoogleAPI mService;


Runnable drawPathRunnable =new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (index<polyLineList.size()-1);
         {
            index++;
            next = index +1;
        }
        if (index < polyLineList.size()-1)
        {
            startPosition = polyLineList.get(index);
            endPosition = polyLineList.get(next);
        }

        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                if (valueAnimator != null) {
                    v = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                    lng = v * endPosition.longitude + (1 - v) * startPosition.longitude;
                    lat = v * endPosition.latitude + (1 - v) * startPosition.latitude;
                    LatLng newPos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    carMarker.setPosition(newPos);
                    carMarker.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                    carMarker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition, newPos));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(newPos).zoom(15.5f).build()));
                }

            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
        handler.postDelayed(this,3000);
    }
};

private float getBearing(LatLng startPosition, LatLng endPosition) {
    double lat = Math.abs(startPosition.latitude - endPosition.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(startPosition.longitude - endPosition.longitude);

    if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude < endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)));
    else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude < endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) ((90-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)))+90);
    else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat))+180);
    else if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) ((90-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)))+270);
        return -1;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    handler = new Handler();
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Init View
    location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
    location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isOnline) {
            if (isOnline)
            {
                startLocationUpdates();
                displayLocation();
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are online",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else
            {
                stopLocationUpdates();
                if (mCurrent != null){
                    mCurrent.remove();
                }

                mMap.clear();
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawPathRunnable);
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are offline",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });

    polyLineList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Places API
    places = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            if (location_switch.isChecked())
            {
                destination = place.getAddress().toString();
                destination = destination.replace(" ", "+");
                getDirection();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Please change your status to ONLINE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, ""+status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //Geo Fire
    drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.driver_tbl);
    geoFire = new GeoFire (drivers);

    setUpLocation();

    mService = Common.getGoogleAPI();
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

private void getDirection() {
    currentPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    String requestApi = null;
    try{

        requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+
                "mode=driving&"+
                "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"+
                "origin="+currentPosition.latitude+","+currentPosition.longitude+"&"+
                "destination="+destination+"&"+
                "Key="+ getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);
        Log.d("EDMTDEV",requestApi);// Print URL for debug
        mService.getPath(requestApi)
                .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONArray routeArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                                JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                                String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
                                polyLineList = decodePoly(encodedString);

                            }


                            if (!polyLineList.isEmpty()) {
                                //Adjusting bounds
                                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                                for (LatLng latLng : polyLineList) {
                                    builder.include(latLng);
                                }
                                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                                CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 2);
                                mMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);
                            }

                            polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                            polylineOptions.width(5);
                            polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            polylineOptions.addAll(polyLineList);
                            greyPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                            blackPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            blackPolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                            blackPolylineOptions.width(5);
                            blackPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(blackPolylineOptions);

                            if (!polyLineList.isEmpty()) {
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(polyLineList.get(polyLineList.size() - 2))
                                        .title("Pickup Location"));
                            }


                            //Animation
                            ValueAnimator polyLineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100);
                            polyLineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                            polyLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                            polyLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                    List<LatLng> points = greyPolyline.getPoints();
                                    int percentValue = (int)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                    int size = points.size();
                                    int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue/100.0f));
                                    List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0,newPoints);
                                    blackPolyline.setPoints(p);
                                }
                            });
                            polyLineAnimator.start();

                            carMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition)
                            .flat(true)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));

                            handler = new Handler();
                            index=-1;
                            next=1;
                            handler.postDelayed(drawPathRunnable,3000);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private List decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List poly = new ArrayList();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}


//Press Ctrl+O


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

            {
                if (checkPlayServices())
                {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    if (location_switch.isChecked())
                        displayLocation();
                }
            }
            break;

    }
}

private void setUpLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        //Request runtime permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    else
    {
       if (checkPlayServices())
       {
           buildGoogleApiClient();
           createLocationRequest();
           if (location_switch.isChecked())
               displayLocation();
       }
    }

}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mlocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mlocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mlocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mlocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    this.mLocationRequest = mlocationRequest;


}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,this,PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST).show();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}


private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
}

private void displayLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null)
    {
        if (location_switch.isChecked())
        {
            final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            //Update to firebase
            geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                    //Add marker
                    if (mCurrent != null)
                        mCurrent.remove(); //Remove already marker
                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                                .title("Your Location"));

                    // Move camera to this position
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));
                }
            });
        }
        else
            {
                Log.d("Error", "Cannot get your location");
            }
    }

}

private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final float startRotation = mCurrent.getRotation();
    final long duration = 1500;


    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
            float rot = t*i+(1-t)*startRotation;
            mCurrent.setRotation(-rot > 180?rot/2:rot);
            if (t<1.0)
            {
                handler.postDelayed(this,16);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 5));
    displayLocation();
}
}
```

Here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mac.uberclone">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<!--

     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
                  android:required="false" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"></activity>
</application>
```

What could be the solution to this? because it seem to be working before all of a sudden it stopped working. I need solution please. Nothing out there seem to have worked

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see if your requests are actually returning good values? That is, you should know if this is a rendering problem or a processing problem. The idea is to show some of your research so we aren't all starting from nothing.

Comment: has your code to ask permission to access location shown correctly? Also, one thing you can do is, when a user click on the switch, if the permission is not granted, open the dialog to ask that permission instead of directly return without doing anything

Comment: @jdv, yes I have debugged and the code rendered well without any processing problem. I am in a dilema

Comment: @Macmist,I don't even know where to ask the permission. Can you please present an example and where to ask the permission

Comment: @PhilipsBobby so, did you determine if you are successfully sending and receiving API data? Does it change when expected? This is the sort of research you should share with us as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: @jdv, my Logcat does not show any errors. So how can I know if its sending and receiving the API data

Comment: Well, there is a built-in debugger in your IDE. You can also just use logcat to output results and tell you where it is in the code, and what some specific values are (so-called printf debugging) so you can test logic and data. The fact is that you have some code you have written that compiles, but isn't doing what you expect. Assert that the parts you think are working are actually working, and maybe even talk to a rubber duck about it. Ref: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/